# LINQ: events grouped by time

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

This code seeks groups of events that occurred together.
Max 5 seconds between them. And more then 5 seconds between groups.

**Update:** Group is List of DateTimes. One group contains DateTimes between which less than 5 seconds. DateTimes which occured more then 5 second placing to next group.

```
public static List<List<DateTime>> GetGroups(int count)
{
  var groups = new List<List<DateTime>>();
  groups.Add(new List<DateTime>());

  using (var db = new DbContainer())
  {
    foreach (var row in db.Table)
    {
      if (!groups.Last().Any() || (groups.Last().Any() && (row.Time - groups.Last().Last()).TotalSeconds <= 5))
      {
        groups.Last().Add(row.Time);
      }
      else if (groups.Count < count)
      {
        groups.Add(new List<DateTime>());
        groups.Last().Add(row.Time);
        continue;
      }

      if (groups.Count == count)
      {
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  return groups;
}
```

Can I implement the same algoritm in LINQ in one or two expressions?

Comment: Looks like that code won't compile.

Comment: @M.Babcock - `groups.Add(new List<DesktopMediaInfo>());`

Comment: @scazy - So you're trying to convert code that doesn't work to LINQ?

Comment: @M.Babcock - just I am trying to prevent strange Timeout exception on `break` statement.

Comment: @scazy - Rather than asking about some code that doesn't work you may consider asking about some code that reproduces your 'strange Timeout exception' so we can help you answer it.

Comment: @M.Babcock - Ok, I shall create new relevant question. But this question is also of interest to me.

Comment: @scazy - Even so you'll need to add detail to your question. What is `group`?

Comment: @M.Babcock - `group` is bool. Always is `true`. I have removed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, the only tricky part about your query that's hard to express with standard LINQ to Objects operators is grouping items based on how close *consecutive* ones are to each other.

For this alone, I would use an iterator block:

```
// Needs argument-checking, but you'll need another method to do it eagerly.
public static IEnumerable<List<T>> GroupByConsective<T>
      (this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, T, bool> prevNextPredicate)
{
    var currentGroup = new List<T>();

    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        if (!currentGroup.Any() || prevNextPredicate(currentGroup.Last(), item))
            currentGroup.Add(item); // Append: empty group or nearby elements.
        else
        {
            // The group is done: yield it out
            // and create a fresh group with the item.
            yield return currentGroup;
            currentGroup = new List<T> { item };
        }
    }

   // If the group still has items once the source is fully consumed,
   // we need to yield it out.
   if(currentGroup.Any())
     yield return currentGroup;
}
```

For everything else (projection, capping the number of groups, materializing to a collection), standard LINQ to Objects will work fine. And so your query becomes:

```
using (var db = new DbContainer())
{
   var groups = db.Table
                  .Select(row => row.Time)
                  .GroupByConsecutive((prev, next) => next.Subtract(prev)
                                                          .TotalSeconds <= 5)
                  .Take(count)
                  .ToList();

  // Use groups...

}
```

Comment: looks pretty ...and works respectably ...and universal for sequences. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
.GroupBy(obj => long.Parse(obj.time.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")) /5 )
```

use datetime.ToString() with format to gen number for each second then / 5 for every 5 sec

Edit:
I wasn't quite sure what u r looking but i tried this and it works

```
var now = DateTime.Now;

            Console.WriteLine(now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss"));

            Enumerable.Range(0, 57)
                .Select(offset => now.AddSeconds(offset))
                .GroupBy(interval => long.Parse(interval.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")) / 5)
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(g => Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} - {2}", g.Count(), g.Min().ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss"), g.Max().ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")));

            Console.ReadKey();
```

Here is the sample output

```
20120125144606
4: 20120125144606 - 20120125144609
5: 20120125144610 - 20120125144614
5: 20120125144615 - 20120125144619
5: 20120125144620 - 20120125144624
5: 20120125144625 - 20120125144629
5: 20120125144630 - 20120125144634
5: 20120125144635 - 20120125144639
5: 20120125144640 - 20120125144644
5: 20120125144645 - 20120125144649
5: 20120125144650 - 20120125144654
5: 20120125144655 - 20120125144659
3: 20120125144700 - 20120125144702
```

Sample datetime is groupped with 5 sec interval. eg second from 10 - 14. If u want 11 - 15 u could add 1 sec before devide
:)

Comment: dividing by five works incorrect for my situation. and `long.Parse` not supported by EF4.